Very slow to work with table using PostgreSQL
I have a table labelled SALES. It has indexes like this list
    "sales_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "sales_order_date_idx" btree (order_date)
    "sales_product_id_idx" btree (product_id)
    "sales_shop_id_idx" btree (shop_id)
    "sales_shop_item_index" UNIQUE, btree (shop_id, order_id, line_item_id)
    "sales_source_idx" btree (source)
    "sales_variant_id_idx" btree (variant_id)
    "sales_vendor_idx" btree (vendor)
    "shop_sales_order_date_idx" btree (order_date) INCLUDE (shop_id, order_id)

ANALYZE shows this data:
analyze verbose sales;
INFO:  analyzing "public.sales"
INFO:  "sales": scanned 30000 of 1155479 pages, containing 763760 live rows and 90012 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 29416955 estimated total rows
ANALYZE

My problem is, if I have an account with say shop_id = 111, and I do a simple query like:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SALES WHERE shop_id=111;
It takes a minute for the result, as that shop has 650,000 entries in the table. So almost everything I do with this table can be dangerously slow!! I feel like I have made a bonehead mistake, and overlooking simplicity. Can anyone point me in the right direction to speed up queries I make on this table? I need to make is speedier for basic queries, inserts, and supporting reports. Things like aggregates on Sales for a month in 2024 should not take minutes to generate!
I used EXPLAIN on my query and it came back like this:
Aggregate  (cost=605728.30..605728.30 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on sales  (cost=8307.89..605465.79 rows=525017 width=0)
         Recheck Cond: (shop_id = 111)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sales_shop_id_idx  (cost=0.00..8281.64 rows=525017 width=0)
               Index Cond: (shop_id = 111)
 JIT:
   Functions: 5
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true


SELECT count(*) may be a simple query, but it is not necessary a cheap query. Is that your real use case? With bigger amounts of data, some queries will always be slow. What you need to achieve is to get the queries you actually need to run fast enough. Moreover, if you ask a performance question, please include EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) output.

count is notoriously slow, if you need it regularly, you could have another table and stored there the actual count with triggers to keep value correct

I am just using count(*) as a whipping boy. I am sure that I am suffering from slowness due to the way I have indexed this table, and maybe that is a better angle for to try and figure out? Is my indexing plan stupid?

Please consider reading this advice

Thanks @mustaccio. Clearly I have neglected my efforts to remain informed of the myriad components involved. That advice list will take many weeks for me to absorb!

This particular problem is not caused by your indexing.  Your indexing should be fine for this.  The problem might be that your table is not vacuumed well enough.  You could just preemptively run VACUUM on the table, or you make sure track_io_timing is on and then look at the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) .

I did a vacuum. The select ran in 105ms which kinda blows my mind. Thanks!
